# Default Git master branch checkout in Travis CI build when using go get

Tags: git, github, parse-platform, go, travis-ci

I'm having some difficulties getting my first attempts at an Travis CI build working.

I'm using Parse(.com) as a backend and have then found an example of using Travis for build and deployment [here](http://www.sheki.in/post/autodeploy-hugo/). However having tried to set it up as best I could I now gotten to a problem which *Google* can't help with.

I'm getting this error from the Travis CI build log.

```
....
$ mkdir -p "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/gosrc"
$ mkdir -p "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/static"
$ curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash
$ go get -v github.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxx
github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx (download)
cd /home/travis/build/xxxxx/xxxxx/gosrc/src/github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx; git checkout master

error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

package github.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx: exit status 1

The command "go get -v github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

This is my install section of the .travis.yml file

```
install:
- mkdir -p "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/gosrc"
- mkdir -p "$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/static"
- curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash
- go get -v github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx
```

My question is: Can you, when conducting a **go get {git repo}**, specify which branch it's supposed to checkout? So it doesn't default to master. If **not** is there a better way of doing this?

Note: I don't have a master branch in my repository, having removed it some time ago because I didn't use it. Do I need to add one for this to work?

Please let me know if the question is unclear or if it's missing some needed information.

Thankful for any help!

Comment: Hi, based on some googling about the `git` error you are getting, can you try doing a `git fetch` before your `git checkout` command?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that No, you can't specify a branch or tag with `go get`. However, if you inspect the [source of the `go` tool](http://golang.org/src/cmd/go/vcs.go?s=2564:2598#L99) you will see that it doesn't really specify `master` either when it's doing a clone. It just clones the repo. This is probably really a git/GitHub issue.

Can you open a terminal and just clone that repo to some other location? Does it give you a complaint about not having the `master` branch? Repositories have a setting for which branch should be the default and if it's still defaulting to `master` even though you don't have one then you'll see the error. I reproduced this by making a GitHub repo without a master branch. I was able to fix it by going into my GitHub repo settings and specifying the default branch.

Note: The `go get` command will specify the `master` branch if your local repo is in a detached head state. Looking at the output I don't think that's what's happening here.